# Inconsistency between boost::regex and std::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost

I'm coding with `boost::regex` and it seems like it doesn't give same result with C++11's `std::regex`.

Consider Following simple code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#include <regex>
#else // defined(_MSC_VER) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#endif // defined(_MSC_VER) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)

namespace {
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
using std::regex;
using std::regex_replace;
#else // defined(_MSC_VER) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
using boost::regex;
using boost::regex_replace;
#endif // defined(_MSC_VER) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
} // namespace

int main() {
    std::string input = "abc.txt";
    ::regex re("[.]", ::regex::extended);

    std::string output = ::regex_replace(input, re, "\\.");

    std::cout << "Result : " << output << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

C++11 Version (GCC 5.4, [GCC 8.0 in wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nfd0GmECdnKXjiXM), MSVC 2015) gives `Result : abc\.txt`

However, C++03 with Boost 1.64 version ([GCC 8.0 in wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nQluOYHl0EJJRaV0)) gives `Result : abc.txt`

I also tried to `::regex::extended` instead of `::regex::ECMAScript` but they are same.

Is there are unknown ***MAGIC*** inconsistencies from `boost::regex` and `std::regex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is deliberated or not.
There is a `boost::regex_constants::format_literal` which can use as the fourth parameter for `regex_replace`, then you can get the same result as std::regex_replace. But there is no `format_literal` in standard c++ libraries.

Comment: I didn't know that such options matters! Thanks @He Ming